# Self study - Determining function codomain to study convergence

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, convergence

I'm having a serious problem in and old exam paper, specifically a question on convergence of random variables.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$, so with density function $f_{X}(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and same for Y.

Let $Z_{n}=\frac{nX}{X+nY}$ for $n\geqslant 1$ (with $n\in \mathbb{N}$) be sequence of random variables. The question is to study almost sure convergence and convergence in distribution for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Now, I have the solution to this problem, and would not like to see it before trying it myself. I'm given however a hint in the text: $Z_{n}$ belong almost surely to $(0,n)$. Question: how did he even find out that $Z_{n}\in (0,n)$ a.s.?

Comment: Could you work it out if the function had been $\frac{1}{n}+(Y/X)$? What about the reciprocal of that ... what would that turn out to be? From there you should see how to do it

Comment: @Glen_b I can see that $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{Y}{X} \in (0,\infty)$ and that grouping up some factors gives me the reciprocal expression. Taking the reciprocal, I can see that the function is undefined for $X+nY=0$, or $n=-\frac{X}{Y}$, which is however never the case! Still can't see where that n pops out. I'll think about it more with you hints and tell you if I find out! Thank you

Comment: sorry, but your initial answer implies that Y/X could go negative. What's the limits on Y/X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(Y/X)$ is on $(0,\infty)$
 so $\frac{1}{n}+Y/X$ is on $(?,\infty)$,
and therefore $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+Y/X}$ must be on $(?,?)$.

Now multiply numerator and denominator so as to get rid of the fractions in the denominator.

Comment: I see where I was mistaken. $\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{Y}{X}$ is on $(\frac{1}{n} , \infty)$ as the reciprocal is on $(0,n)$. Thank you. Probably just have to practice more to figure ranges out more immediately.